# How to show the updated row in a textview?

Tags: android, database

So I'm creating a simple contacts app and got stuck with showing the updated row in a textview. I made a comment in the method "openUpdateDialog" cause there is the problem that I need help with. I hope that my code is easy to understand and thanks for the help guys.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


DatabaseHandler handler;
Context context = this;
ListView listView;
String textFromEtNameAdd;
String textFromEtPhoneAdd;
String textFromListViewName;
String textFromListViewPhone;
String textFromListViewID;
Contact singleContact;
int idAsIntegerFromListview;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);


    if (listView != null) {

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                TextView tvNameFromListView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameID);
                TextView tvPhoneFromListView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneID);
                TextView tvIDFromListView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rowID);

                textFromListViewName = tvNameFromListView.getText().toString();
                textFromListViewPhone = tvPhoneFromListView.getText().toString();
                textFromListViewID = tvIDFromListView.getText().toString();
                idAsIntegerFromListview = Integer.parseInt(textFromListViewID);

                singleContact = handler.getContact(id);


                openUpdateDialog();


            }
        });


        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, final long id) {

                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_delete_popup, popup.getMenu());
                popup.show();

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {

                            case R.id.deleteItemID:


                                Contact contact = new Contact(id);

                                handler.deleteContact(contact);

                                printDatabase();


                                break;


                        }


                        return true;
                    }
                });


                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    handler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    printDatabase();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.addContactID) {

        openAddDialog();


    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void printDatabase() {

    Cursor c = handler.getAllContacts();


    String[] fromColumns = {handler.KEY_NAME, handler.KEY_ID, handler.KEY_PH_NO};
    int[] toViews = {R.id.nameID, R.id.rowID, R.id.phoneID};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_custom_listview, c, fromColumns, toViews, 0);


    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}


public void openAddDialog() {

    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder makeDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
    View viewAdd = li.inflate(R.layout.contacts_add_dialog, null);
    makeDialog.setView(viewAdd);


    final EditText etNameAdd = (EditText) viewAdd.findViewById(R.id.etNameID);
    final EditText etPhoneAdd = (EditText) viewAdd.findViewById(R.id.etPhoneID);


    makeDialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            textFromEtNameAdd = etNameAdd.getText().toString();
            textFromEtPhoneAdd = etPhoneAdd.getText().toString();


            Contact contact = new Contact(textFromEtNameAdd, textFromEtPhoneAdd);

            handler.addContact(contact);

            printDatabase();


        }
    });

    makeDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    android.app.AlertDialog ad = makeDialog.create();
    ad.show();


}

public void openUpdateDialog() {

    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder makeDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
    View viewUpdate = li.inflate(R.layout.contacts_add_dialog, null);
    makeDialog.setView(viewUpdate);


    final EditText etNameUpdate = (EditText) viewUpdate.findViewById(R.id.etNameID);
    final EditText etPhoneUpdate = (EditText) viewUpdate.findViewById(R.id.etPhoneID);


    final String singleContactName = singleContact.get_name();
    final String singleContactPhone = singleContact.get_phone_number();

    etNameUpdate.setText(singleContactName);
    etPhoneUpdate.setText(singleContactPhone);


    makeDialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            //name and phone goes in the parenthesis but its storing the old value :/
            Contact contact = new Contact();

            handler.updateContact(contact);

            printDatabase();


        }
    });

    makeDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    android.app.AlertDialog ad = makeDialog.create();
    ad.show();


}


}
```

Contact.java:

```
public class Contact {


long _id;
String _name;
String _phone_number;

public Contact() {


}


public Contact(long _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public Contact(String _name, String _phone_number) {
    this._name = _name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}

public Contact(long _id, String _name, String _phone_number) {
    this._id = _id;
    this._name = _name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}


public long get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(long _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String get_name() {
    return _name;
}

public void set_name(String _name) {
    this._name = _name;
}

public String get_phone_number() {
    return _phone_number;
}

public void set_phone_number(String _phone_number) {
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return _name;
}
}
```

DatabaseHandler.java:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);


    onCreate(db);
}


void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.get_name());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.get_phone_number());
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public Contact getContact(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

    return contact;
}


public Cursor getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.set_name(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.set_phone_number(cursor.getString(2));

            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    return cursor;
}


public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.get_name());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.get_phone_number());


    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.get_id())});
}


public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.get_id())});
    db.close();
}


}
```

Comment: what is error you are getting exactly....post logcat here

Comment: just add this adapter.notifyOnDataSetChanged() below listview.setAdapter()method. May be that will help you.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, its just not showing the updated row. it always shows the old value. Example: I want to add a new contact and I put name:"myname" and for number:"1" then it saves it and then I click on the listview item to edit it cause I dont like the name for example and I wanna change it to:"myname2" but when I type "myname2" it saves it as "myname".

Comment: Jitesh Dalsaniya doesnt help. Refresh of the listview works fine when I delete items etc.

Comment: on click makeDialog.setPositiveButton button you are just creating new contact object but not assigning any value to it and that object you send to update in database. You need to assign value to that created object and then call updateContact method.

Comment: I know, I made a comment above that line. But I dont know which value. The problem is if I assign the text from etNameUpdate and etPhoneUpdate it still returns the old value

Comment: Whatever value you get from edittext store it in local String object not in global string object. See my Answer

Comment: you need to set contact id when you press the update button.
I tried your code and got working by this way

Comment: can you update your answer pls? cause I just tried and it didnt work

Comment: Please check my updated answer. If work then accept it and give upvote !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109870/discussion-between-jitesh-dalsaniya-and-nenco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Change listview onItemClick with below

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                   if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position) instanceof Cursor){
                        Log.e(TAG, "onItemClick: Cursor Object");
                        Cursor c = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        if(c != null){
                            String idd = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(handler.KEY_ID));
                            Log.e(TAG, "onItemClick: idd " +idd);
                            idAsIntegerFromListview = Integer.parseInt(idd);
                        }
                    }

                    singleContact = handler.getContact(idAsIntegerFromListview);
                    openUpdateDialog();

                }
            });
```

Then Change in method openUpdateDialog() as below.

```
makeDialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                //name and phone goes in the parenthesis but its storing the old value :/
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.set_id(idAsIntegerFromListview);
                contact.set_name(etNameUpdate.getText().toString());
                contact.set_phone_number(etPhoneUpdate.getText().toString());
                handler.updateContact(contact);

                printDatabase();


            }
        });
```

It will work I tried your code.

Comment: Contact contact = new Contact(etNameUpdate.getText().toString(),etPhoneUpdate.getText().toString());

                handler.updateContact(contact);

                printDatabase();

Comment: this was my first try and it didnt work, tried yours too, doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is..

`singleContact = handler.getContact(id);`

The id which you are passing to getContact query this is not a database id which have declare in database table. You should understand that this id is adapter id.
For passing database id you have to write a query. first you does get database id by name.

And pass database id of which entry you want to update in Contact class constructor like..

```
//name and phone goes in the parenthesis but its storing the old value :/
        Contact contact = new Contact(etNameUpdate.getText().toString(), etPhoneUpdate .getText().toString(), id);

        handler.updateContact(contact);
```

Comment: I know what you mean but delete method is working perfectly. so it makes no sense that this is the problem cause I'm getting the contact by ID and I'm also deleting it by ID. So my logic is that both of these methods shouldnt work then

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with your update method you have closed db before operation.

```
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.get_name());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.get_phone_number());


        int noOfUpdatedRow=db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.get_id())});
        db.close();
        return noOfUpdatedRow;
    }
```

Comment: removed db.close() but its still getting me the old value

Comment: in Contact contact = new Contact(); method which value you are passing
is it etNameUpdate.getText()?

Comment: ye, but I tried passing texts from those 2 fields and it didnt work.

Comment: You need to pass id also it is not reflecting to your database,you will always get updated value from edit text.